# Access a method outside an object via onclick in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new with JS and I haven't encountered these challenges yet. Its been 6 hours past and I do not know where to start considering I do not know what exactly happened.

So far, I have created an Object name "Tags". One of the methods of the said object is "onDelete", which should be executed after "onclick" event.

```
function Tags( element ) {

    let arrayOfList     = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
    let DOMParent       = document.querySelector( element )
    let DOMList
    let DOMInput

    function DOMCreate() {
        let ul      = document.createElement('ul')
        let li      = document.createElement('li')
        let input   = document.createElement('input')

        DOMParent.appendChild( ul )
        DOMParent.appendChild( input )

        DOMList     = DOMParent.firstElementChild
        DOMInput = DOMParent.lastElementChild
    }

    function DOMRender() {
        // clear the entire <li> inside <ul> 
        DOMList.innerHTML = ''

        // render each <li> to <ul>
        arrayOfList.forEach( function( currentValue, index ) {
            DOMList.innerHTML += `<li>${currentValue} <a href='#' onclick='onDelete(${index})'>&times;</li>`
        })
    }

    function onKeyUp() {
        DOMInput.addEventListener( 'keyup', function() {
            let text = this.value.trim()

            if ( text.includes(',') ) {
                // check if empty text when ',' is remove
                if ( text.replace(',', '') != '') {
                    // push to array and remove ','
                    arrayOfList.push( text.replace(',' , '') )
                }
                // clear input
                this.value = ''
            }

            DOMRender()
        })
    }

    function onDelete( id ) {
        console.log( id )
    }

    DOMCreate()
    DOMRender()
    onKeyUp()
}

new Tags("#div_tags")
```

HTML was simply:

```
<div id="div_tags"></div>
```

Now, I have examine the DOM, and onlick was present, see:
[image]

However, when a tag was click I received **Uncaught ReferenceError: onDelete is not defined**

Could someone enlighten me, please?

Comment: Don't use the `onclick` attribute. Instead use `.addEventListener()` like you already do in `onKeyUp()`

Comment: produce a minimum verifiable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onDelete` identifier is scoped only inside the `Tags` function, but `onclick` inline handlers can only see globally-scoped variables, so `onclick="onDelete(0)` throws an error, because the inline handler can't see the locally-scoped `onDelete`.

While you could fix it by assigning `onDelete` to `window`, it'd be better to avoid inline handlers entirely - they have scope problems and are generally considered to be pretty poor practice. Instead, attach the event listener to the created `a` with `addEventListener` (and append the `li`s to the `ul` via `appendChild` instead of concatenating with `innerHTML`, so that the listeners doesn't get corrupted on later iterations - assigning to the `innerHTML` of a container removes any listeners it had previously)

```
function DOMRender() {
    // clear the entire <li> inside <ul> 
    DOMList.innerHTML = ''

    // render each <li> to <ul>
    arrayOfList.forEach( function( currentValue, index ) {
        const li = DOMList.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
        li.innerHTML = `${currentValue} <a href='#'>&times;</a>`
        li.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => onDelete(index));
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation @CertainPerformance. In fact, this is working on my end, and I find your approach helpful.